# How to run route in Laravel using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a route in my web route in Laravel. The route is given following:

```
Route::post('addCustomer', 'UserController@addCustomer')->name('addCustomer');
```

I want to run this method in my Laravel application using AJAX and jQuery. My controller method is given below:

```
 public function addCustomer(Request $request) {
    $userManager = new UserManager();
    
    $userName=$request->input('customerName');
    $phoneNumber=$request->input('phoneNumber');
    $address=$request->input('address');
    $email=$request->input('email');
    $password="customer";
    
    $userManager->addCustomer($userName, $phoneNumber, $address, $email, $password);
}
```

[Please See the following Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WajYv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    $('#addCustomerButton').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */

        // serialize method
        var data = $('#addCustomerForm').serialize();

        // if you're not wrapping the input fields inside a form
        var data = {
            customerName: $('input[name="customerName"]').val(),
            phoneNumber: $('input[name="phoneNumber"]').val(),
            address: $('input[name="address"]').val(),
            email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/addCustomer',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            complete: function (jqXHR) {},
        });
    });
```